# How to run a application which is in the same directory as a Python script?

Tags: python, directory

```
def run():
    subprocess.call("C://Users//FIN//Documents//python//react_bot//discord bot//dist//app.exe",shell=True)
    print("app loaded")

run()
```

I have this code which will call and open the application which is in C://Users//FIN//Documents//python//react_bot//discord bot//dist directory because i have my stuff there.
What if i want to call for an application which is in the same directory as the python script. How do i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first get the parent directory of current script and join it with the application name and run it:

```
import os
import subprocess

mydir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
theapp = os.path.join(mydir, 'YOUR APPLICATION NAME.EXTENSION')
subprocess.call(theapp)
```

Comment: I love it when other people copy my awnser almost word for word and post it two minutes after mine

Comment: @Lemon nooo, i have posted answer on my own. Then i have to first think a few 30 seconds what the problem is (if the questiom is badly phrased sometimes it takes shorter) then start to prepare a solution, and then post it. If im in full site don't expand "n new answers to this question". Upvote for you

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to solve your problem with the following:

```py
import os
import subprocess

dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
cmd = os.path.join(dirname, 'app.exe')

subprocess.call(cmd)
```